# How would you implement a java plugin system without any shared API?

Tags: java, api, plugins, introspection

To set up a plugin system, I am aware that the common way is to create an API part (let's say a jar) and an implementation part, for each plugin. Thus, if a plugin A need B, A must know the API of B, sadly, "at compile time"...

**Is there a way to develop plugins by removing any code dependencies between them ?**
The idea is that developpers should use convention and documentation, not code. I am aware this way is much more dangerous and don't follow the java paradigm but... I am just curious :) Any solutions are welcome (message broker, hook, introspection, annotation, de/serialization...)

Currently the only solution I see is to re-create all classes on which a plugin depends and call real objects inside with introspection... It's works. But it's ugly.

```
public class User { // user object in plugin A

  private Object realUserObject;        // User object from UserPlugin

  public User(Object realUserObject) {
    this.realUserObject = realUserObject;
  }

  public String getName() throws Exception {
    Method method = realUserObject.getClass().getMethod("getName");
    return (String) method.invoke(realUserObject);
  }

  public void setName(String name) throws Exception {
    Method method = realUserObject.getClass().getMethod("getName");
    method.invoke(realUserObject, name);
  }

}
```

In this scenario, it could be interesting if java compiler let us call an undeclared method since a class got a special annotation (which generate a kind of dynamic proxy in order to intercept all calls). Thus the only developper task would be to bind the external object to a very simple and existing one inside its plugin.

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head. If you don't have even a common interface to start from, knowing what to expose / call / etc requires special effort, and will have unknown results.

Comment: I fail to see where this would be a good idea. In any case, doing this in Java would have to rely heavily on reflection, which makes things even worse. Other languages like Scala have ways to operate on type signatures, that is probably as close as you could get to 'undeclared methods' - still, just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of choices: SOA, aspects, interpreted language blocks, etc...

Java is compilable language, this is why we usually provide shared api - it is much simpler to support such eco-systems. However you are free to choose any language you want to solve your tasks.

Do you really need java in such context?